# Gnome Software - is there a search function?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu

I've just installed Xubuntu 18.04 LTS on a small netbook. Now I want to install a couple of specific applications (Konquerer or similar for one) and darn if I can find a search bar anywhere in the Gnome Software screen. Am I just missing something? Or do I have to just go through everything in there looking for it?

Or ... is there a better way to find and install new software?

Thanks -- Howard

Comment: In the top-right corner (Gnome software, 19.04) there is a little magnifying glass...

Comment: Konquerer is a KDE/QT-based app, whereas XFCE is GTK-based, so it will pull lots of KDE/QT deps just for one app, using up your drive. Maybe, try to use Chromium/Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Ah, I see this is for netbook. So, chrome/firefox can be too much burden. Try `epiphany-browser` then.

Answer (score 2):

**1:** As pointed out in comments, there's a little magnifying glass icon. Click on that to get a search bar:

[image: Search bar location]

**2:** Are you really sure you want to install Konqueror on your Xubuntu system? As pointed out in comments, it may pull in many dependencies because it uses a different toolkit, qt, than applications present normally on Xubuntu which is gtk2/gtk3.

**3:** Unfortunately, even though Konqueror is available in the universe repository (and the universe repository is enabled on the desktop version of all Ubuntu flavors), gnome-software doesn't seem to find it, both on Xubuntu 18.04 and on Ubuntu 18.04:

**Konqueror not found in Xubuntu 18.04**

[image: konqueror missing in Xubuntu]

**Konqueror not found in Ubuntu 18.04**

[image: konqueror missing in Ubuntu]

However, Synaptic Package Manager and the terminal route have no difficulty in finding and offering to install Konqueror.

**Synaptic Package Manager finds Konqueror in Xubuntu**

[image: konqueror in spm]

**Terminal output**

```
dkb@dkb:~$ apt policy konqueror
konqueror:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

The `apt policy` output tells me that Konqueror isn't currently installed but **is** available.

Installing Konqueror from the command-line:

All that is needed is for you to run `sudo apt install konqueror` from the terminal and to provide your password. There'll be a lot of output because Konqueror pulls in many dependencies (and maybe some additional recommended software) on Xubuntu. Anyway, the last few lines of output look like this:

```
0 upgraded, 134 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 83.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 341 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

---

Some concluding comments:

- I don't know why you want to install Konqueror but I suggest thinking twice if you're new to Linux and someone has casually recommended you install it.
- I feel "Software Centers" such as gnome software and KDE's Discovery are works in progress and shouldn't be regarded as final authorities on what can or can't be installed.
- Synaptic Package Manager is totally worth installing even if you don't need it immediately.

---

Further reading:

- [What are dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361741/what-are-dependencies)
- [What are recommends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77053/apt-installing-more-packages-than-specified-as-dependencies)
- Toolkits in Linux: [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3501) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits)

Comment: [Muon](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000768/66509) may be an option too. Currently I like it more than Synaptic.

Comment: @N0rbert I frankly forgot about muon but given that the poster is on Xubuntu, muon too would pull in qt dependencies: I can't say how many until I boot into a Xubuntu session.

Answer (score 1):

I usually will install synaptic and use that to do software searches. you can install it from a terminal by doing the following `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install synaptic` after it install launch synaptic and search for the software your looking for. There is also software center that has a search function it come pre installed on ubuntu flavors.  If you installed xubuntu you do not have gnome software as such.

Comment: OK, that worked. I didn't quite know where to find synaptic afterward -- I hit the thing at the left end of the panel and selected 'all'. Bingo! Now what I want to do is find a 2-panel file manager like 'Total Commander' with FTP included if possible.   I'll do some exploring.

Comment: @HowardBallinger 2panel file manager is `mc` (Midnight commander). And you can try XFCE `Thunar` to the same effect (it has tabs instead of panels).