# Partial upgrade wants to remove an application I installed - why?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 20.10

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 and when I open Software Updater, it wants to remove Discord, which I previously installed manually with GDebi. Why does it want to remove Discord and can I stop that, but continue with the other package changes?

[image: Image of the partial upgrade window]

Comment: You'll be able to install it later if it is available for 20.10.

Comment: @pilot6 Ok, so I should let it remove Discord and then re-install it?

Comment: You have no options ;-)

Comment: Most probably this version of Dicord conflicts with the upgraded version of Ubuntu. To understand this better see [What are dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361741/what-are-dependencies) To avoid this problem you can install the `snap` version of Discord. Search within the **Ubuntu Software** app and install from there.

Comment: See [What is the snap packaging format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761245/what-is-the-snap-packaging-format) for more on snap vs deb packages. To avoid dependency issues you should not manually install packages when possible. Install using `sudo apt install <packagename> and and if it is not available in the repositories, then choose the snap version if available. These packages are much bigger than deb packages, because they are self contained and do not depend on other packages.